# xpath html get all columns 1 and 2 together and concatenate with column ":"

Tags: html, linux, bash, xpath, xmllint

I have this following command that gets the data from column 2:

Table example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
        <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>



wget -q -O - http://www.example.com | xmllint --html --xpath "//table[@id=\"tableID\"]//tr//td[position() = 2]//text() - 2>/dev/null
```

That outputs something like:

```
12345
```

How can I get all both column 1 and column 2 with ":" symbol that appends on each line?

Desired output:

```
a:1
b:2
c:3
d:4
e:5
```

Answer (score 1):

With **xmlstarlet** and **awk**:

```
wget -q -O - "http://www.example.com" | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//tr/td" -n \
| awk -F'\n' -v RS= '{ n=NF/2; for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $i ":" $(i+n) }'
```

The output:

```
a:1
b:2
c:3
d:4
e:5
```

Comment: it does not work. gives me this error:  wget -q -O - https://www.socks-proxy.net | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//table//tr/td" -n \ | awk -F'\n' -v RS= '{ n=NF/2; for(i=1;i<=N;i++) print $i ":" $(i+n) }'
failed to load external entity " "
root@debian:~#

Comment: @user2317589, it does work in case if your `wget` call returns the content as you posted in the question. Otherwise, you have posted wrong data

Comment: I created another question here with output and desired output. thanks again for your help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114719/xpath-html-combine-columns?noredirect=1#comment81179235_47114719

Answer (score 1):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), which, unlike `xmllint` and `xmlstarlet`, supports XPath/XQuery 3.1:

```
$ xidel -s "<file-or-url>" -e '
  for $col in 1 to count(//tr[1]/td) return
  join(
    for $row in 1 to count(//tr) return
    //tr[$row]/td[$col],
    ":"
  )
'
a:1
b:2
c:3
d:4
e:5
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved from: [xpath html combine columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114719/xpath-html-combine-columns/47115620#47115620)

solution:

```
wget -q -O - "https://socks-proxy.net" \
| xmllint --html --xpath "//table[@id='proxylisttable']//tr//td[position() < 3]" - 2>/dev/null 
| tidy -cq -omit -f /dev/null | xmllint --html --xpath "//td/text()" - | paste - - -d':'
```

many thanks to @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: you really should not duplicate answers as your own