# xpath html combine columns

Tags: linux, bash, xpath, xmlstarlet, xmllint

I'm trying to extract data from socks-proxy.net with the IP and port from the website table.

I'm using these commands in linux to get the IP and port. How can I combine theme?

```
wget -q -O - "https://socks-proxy.net" | xmllint --html --xpath "//table[@id=\"proxylisttable\"]//tr//td[1]//text()" - 2>/dev/null
```

Output:

```
103.254.12.3393.12.55.94192:12:44:11
```

It combines the IP and it its not good

that will get all the IP's from the website table

```
wget -q -O - "https://socks-proxy.net" | xmllint --html --xpath "//table[@id=\"proxylisttable\"]//tr//td[2]//text()" - 2>/dev/null
```

that will get all the ports

Output:

```
108025951082
```

It combines the port and its not good.

Question: how can I combine them with the desired example output:

```
103.254.12.33:1080
93.12.55.94:2595
192:12:44:11:1082
```

and so on...

Comment: Please add output of wget and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Do you have access to xmlstarlet?

Comment: @Cyrus I edited my post for the output of wget. Yes I do have xmlstarlet.

Comment: Please add output of wget (not xmllint's output) to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus its a long html code from the output of WGET. please see: https://pastebin.com/F14VRNBc

Comment: @user2317589, why did you ignore your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108650/xpath-html-get-all-columns-1-and-2-together-and-concatenate-with-column/47110355?noredirect=1#comment81179391_47110355

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i think was not able to explain on that previous question but thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but seeing you're using 4(!) different tools to accomplish something so simple I just had to jump in to show you another amazing XML parser, called [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), which can do it all by itself:

```
$ xidel -s "https://socks-proxy.net" -e '
  //table[@class="table table-striped table-bordered"]/tbody/tr/x"my{td[5]}://{td[1]}:{td[2]}"
'
mySocks4://103.254.126.130:1080
mySocks5://192.228.194.87:25950
mySocks5://173.162.95.122:62168
mySocks4://183.166.22.194:1080
mySocks5://70.44.216.252:40656
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Complex solution:

```
wget -q -O - "https://socks-proxy.net" \
| xmllint --html --xpath "//table[@id='proxylisttable']//tr//td[position() < 3]" - 2>/dev/null 
| tidy -cq -omit -f /dev/null | xmllint --html --xpath "//td/text()" - | paste - - -d':'
```

The output:

```
103.254.126.130:1080
192.228.194.87:25950
173.162.95.122:62168
183.166.22.194:1080
70.44.216.252:40656
66.83.161.74:34036
37.191.146.151:10200
101.100.171.69:52769
120.92.164.154:62080
216.37.80.226:61226
75.180.14.170:17694
74.221.106.14:10200
208.180.142.167:14846
...
```

---

Extended approach to cover additional fields:

```
wget -q -O - "https://socks-proxy.net" \
| xmllint --html --xpath "//table[@id='proxylisttable']//tr//td[position() < 3]" - 2>/dev/null 
| tidy -cq -omit -f /dev/null | xmllint --html --xpath "//td/text()" - \
| awk -F'\n' -v RS= '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=5) printf "my%s://%s:%s\n",$(i+4),$i,$(i+1) }'
```

The output:

```
mySocks4://103.254.126.130:1080
mySocks5://192.228.194.87:25950
mySocks5://173.162.95.122:62168
mySocks4://183.166.22.194:1080
mySocks5://70.44.216.252:40656
mySocks5://66.83.161.74:34036
mySocks5://37.191.146.151:10200
mySocks5://101.100.171.69:52769
mySocks5://120.92.164.154:62080
....
```

---

P.S. Tested on your input file given by https://pastebin.com/F14VRNBc.

Comment: is it possible to add an if statement from this source https://pastebin.com/F14VRNBc to check from the table column "Version" and add the string mysocks5 or mysocks4 depending of the column 'version'


may I ask please again for your help to output like this:


IF version = Socks5, then make it:
mysocks5://103.254.126.130:1080

and if Socks5, then 
mysocks4://103.254.126.130:1080

and so on...

expected output example:
mysocks4://103.254.126.34:1080
mysocks5://103.14.126.10:1080
mysocks5://103.54.126.130:1080
mysocks4://93.244.126.26:1080
mysocks5://103.254.126.130:1080